# What is the best way to resolve deadlock in httpwebrequest?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, httprequest, httpclient

Recently my server CPU usage is reaching 100% due to unknown reason.

After analyzing the dump file, I found out it could be a deadlock issue in my code.

From the dump file I got following information:

```
This thread is making an HttpWebRequest and waiting on the remote server to respond
HttpRequest URI:https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/api/
ServicePoint - ConnectionLimit:2147483647 CurrentConnections:1
```

I have a task where it makes a http request to the third party API whenever a transaction is created. I am using following method to call the request. This task usually process 4-5 requests in a minute during peak hours.

```
 protected virtual WebResponse GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
    {
      WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
      this.m_WebResponse = response;
      return response;
    }
```

Can somebody explain how could a deadlock happens in such way. Why the server CPU usage is 100%.

Comment: That won't cause a deadlock, maybe the code in the API is not handling async correctly.

Comment: @Crowcoder I checked the code. It is handled in async correctly. It will hit the timeout even there is deadlock in the API. I have no idea why it is saying "this thread is blocked while also blocking other threads"